# Nested span mouseover issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have nested span elements and have `mouseover` and `mouseout` events for the parent span

```
<span id='parent' onmouseover='showChild()' onmouseout='hideChild()'>
    <span id='child'></span>
</span>
```

I am showing `child` span on `mouseover` on `parent` span and hiding it on `mouseout` from `parent`.

This all is working fine in firefox and chrome, but in IE as soon as mouse comes over child element IE considers it as mouse out from parent and so hides the child.

Is there any work around or the correct way to do this for IE?

I can put the same events in child span and that should work in IE also but would it be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the workaround.

I replaced parent span with the `div` with `display:inline-block` and it is working everywhere now!

Thanks!

Comment: Similar issue on Chrome `onwheel` event where the wheel events needed to be on separate spans within a div. The div was catching the event and not passing through to the spans. So, I changed to nested divs as described in the answer and all works perfectly now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably fix this by using `onmouseleave` instead of `onmouseout`:

```
<span id='parent' onmouseover='showChild()' onmouseleave='hideChild()'>
    <span id='child'></span>
</span>
```

The above won't trigger the `hideChild()` when you hover over the child, but it will trigger the `showChild()` when moving between the parent and the child.

To prevent this, you can replace `onmouseover` with `onmouseenter`:

```
<span id='parent' onmouseenter='showChild()' onmouseleave='hideChild()'>
    <span id='child'></span>
</span>
```

Check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7xxbeg6d/). Open the console for the output.

Comment: It is weird that your solution is working in fiddle but when I tried it in my code it is still not working :(

Comment: Weird. What version of IE are you trying this on?

Comment: IE 11. However I found a work around. I posted my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nice! Did you still end up using `onmouseleave` and `onmouseout`?

Comment: Nope, I am using `mouseover` and `mouseout` only as I was originally using. You can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove pointer events from parent div using css:

```
#parent * {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This only works on IE11, as he is having problem with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you just need to check if the event target is not the child, using **[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)**.

This is a working snippet:

```js
function showChild(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var child = document.getElementById("child");
  if (e.target !== child) {
    child.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}

function hideChild(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var child = document.getElementById("child");
  if (e.target !== child) {
    child.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  height:100px;
}
#child {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<span id="parent" onmouseover="showChild(event)" onmouseout="hideChild(event)">Parent
    <span id="child">Child</span>
</span>
```

This will give you what you need.

**Note:**

In Firefox you should pass an `event` argument to your functions, like this `showChild(event)` otherwise it will claim about event `e is undefined`.